# Show by contradiction that $a^n\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $|a|<1$. I have **to show by contradiction** that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n=0.$$
This is how I do:

Let $x_n=a^n$. I know that $(|x_n|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing a under-bounded by $0$. Therefore, $(|x_n|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge. Let denote $\ell=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}|x_n|$ it's limit. I suppose by contradiction that $\ell>0$. I think that I have to find a $N$ such that $a^N<\ell$, but I don't get it. Any idea ?

Comment: Could you use logarithms, perhaps?

Comment: Probably not, but you can propose your answer anyway :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $\ell > 0$. Then $\frac{\ell}{|a|} > \ell$, hence there is an $N$ such that $|a|^N < \frac{\ell}{|a|}$. But this gives the contradiction $|a|^{N+1} < \ell$.