# sequence of $a^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to show that when a $\in \Bbb R$ with $\lvert a\rvert < 1$ the limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a^n = 0$ using the definition of convergence of a sequence. So far I have

$\lvert a^n - 0\rvert < \epsilon$

$\lvert a^n \rvert  < \epsilon$

$\lvert a\rvert^n   < \epsilon$

and

$\lvert a \rvert < 1 $ $\implies$ $\lvert a\rvert^n   < 1$

But I don't see where I am supposed to head with this in order to prove it? any advice would be greatly appreciated in understanding this. Thank you.

Comment: For given $\varepsilon >0$, you have to find $N$ such that for every $n>N$ $|a|^n < \varepsilon$ holds. Note that $N$ may depend on $a$. Note further that $n \mapsto |a|^n$ is decreasing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436423/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking $\ln$ from both sides we have $$n\ln |a|<\ln \epsilon$$and since $\ln |a|<0$ (because $0<|a|<1$) we obtain $$n>{\ln \epsilon\over \ln |a|}$$therefore choose $N={\ln \epsilon\over \ln |a|}$ and you can conclude for any $n>N$ that $|a|^n<\epsilon$ and the proof is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If $|a|<1$, then $1/|a|>1$, hence $\frac{1}{|a|}=1+h$ with some $h>0$. Then we get, with Bernoulli's inequality:

$\frac{1}{|a^n|}=(1+h)^n \ge 1+nh > nh.$

Thus

$|a^n| < \frac{1}{nh}$.

Can you proceed ?